# Post Value Of ID from JSON Array to 'model.UserId'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

JSON Arrary as below

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "Name":"hvhv",
    "Marks":11,
    "Grade":"hvh"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "Name":"f",
    "Marks":12,
    "Grade":"yf"
  },
  {
    "id":3
    "Name":"ds",
    "Marks":13,
    "Grade":"jhj"
  }
]
```

I want all ID from this array in my controller's Method as Model/string Array

i have an object of RegisterModel named as registerModel
and i want to post all 
id to registerModel.UserId
and Name to registerModel.Name

Comment: Use LINQ to load the values into your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive such JSON in your controller action, you may try to work with it as follows.
Create similar model:

```
public class MyModel
{
 public int id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int Marks {get; set;}
 public sytring Grade {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your Controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction (List<MyModel> models)
{
  foreach(var item in models)
  {
    var result = new registerModel 
      {
        name = item.Name,
        userID = id
       }
      //Do somthing with registerModel
   }
}
```

Comment: model value is null when posting array from view

Comment: {
                         type: "Post",
                         url: "/Home/GetBulk",
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: { name: array.Name, marks:array.Marks, grade:array.Grade },
                         traditional: true,
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert("j= " + data);
                         
                     },

                   
                
    });

Comment: array to send is
    var array = [
                          {
                              Name: "Amit",
                              Marks: 11,
                              Grade: "A"
                          },
                          {
                              Name: "Abhishek",
                              Marks: 12,
                              Grade: "A"
                          }                          
                            ]

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the json from the `HttpContext.Request` Object to your List of Model like,

```
        public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
            var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            List<RegisterModel> registerModelList = new List<RegisterModel>();
            resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            if (jsonString != null)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                registerModelList = (List<RegisterModel>)serializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<RegisterModel>));
            }
         }
```